# Can you use the jquery validation plugin to test a string?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've seen examples of using [jquery.validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)  to validate form fields but I have a situation where I have an email address as a string in an object and thought it would be nice to leverage the code in jquery.validate to test it.

Is there any way to do something like:

`var isEmail = $.validate.email("abc@efg.com");`

using the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is a function to strings, use the regex from validation plugin for "email" and create a function around it:

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/QuvSh/

Comment: Yup, that would totally work. I just seems a waste to bloat my JS by duplicating a test that's already been written, so I was hoping to avoid doing this, but your suggestion may be what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

The methods are "exposed", sort of. You could do something like

```
var isEmail = $.validator.methods.email.call({
  optional:function() {
    return false;
  }
},'email@domain.com', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something with writing it in as the value to an input field and then validating that, but I think you'd still need a form to submit it with - probably kludgier than what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah. I mean I can write my own basic email test to catch obvious bad emails but I was hoping the plugin exposed its validation methods in such a way that I could use them instead of duplicating code I'm already referencing.

Comment: Will likely be more trouble than it's worth since plugin validation methods are all tied to fields with names within a form